# Query result is different when executing a simple search in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am executing the following query in a MySQL database (look at SELECT AND WHERE, the rest is not important):

```
SELECT distinct fname //more fields...
FROM filedepot_files AS ff 
INNER JOIN filedepot_categories AS fc 
ON ff.cid = fc.cid 
INNER JOIN filedepot_access AS fa 
ON fc.cid = fa.catid 
WHERE fa.permid=$id AND fname LIKE '%$key%' 
ORDER BY DATE
```

The environment is a PHP script running under Drupal with FileDepot module but I doubt that matters at all.

This is the PHP script (well the part that matters):

```
$id = 1;
$key = $_GET['key'];
$query = .... (see above)
$result = db_query($query);
while($row = db_fetch_array($result)){
    //do stuff
    echo $row['fname'];
}
```

`db_query()` is a Drupal method that allows to easily execute SQL queries and a returns an array, `db_fetch_array()` allows to parse the result.

Now, DB contains the following entries for fname (there are more, these are just examples):

- Dichiarazione 1
- Dichiarazione 2
- Guida 1
- Guida 2

If I launch the script with "guida" as key it correctly returns the two entries both with PHP and MySQL. 
If i use "Guida" it works as well.
However if I use "dichiarazione" it doesnt with PHP while it does with MySQL.
Strange thing is that "Dichiarazione" works both with PHP and MySQL.

What is wrong with the query? I tryed to use `LOWER(fname) LIKE '%$key%'` but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

I am sure there is something stupid that I am missing but I can't seem to find what that is...

Comment: You've got a nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is a special character in Drupal queries (it's used for placeholders). Try double-escaping it:

```
WHERE fa.permid=$id AND fname LIKE '%%$key%%'
```

More worryingly though, you're wide open to SQL injection. Some sanitisation is in order:

```
...
WHERE fa.permid= %d AND fname LIKE '%%%s%%' 
...

$query = db_query($sql, $id, $key);
```

It might look crazy but that's the right number of `%` signs. Two for each literal `%`, and one (`%s`) for the string placeholder

Comment: Thanks twice, first because you solved my problem, second because you noticed my SQL injection problem as well :) Keep in mind that the script above was for testing purposes only.